# How to bypass FastClick with Kendo UI DataViz Chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz, fastclick

We have a web app that is used with iPads and iPhones.  We are using FastClick (https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) to eliminate the 300ms wait time for mobile/tablet users.

This makes everything snappier, but the interaction with the chart (using SVG rendering) is spotty.  Sometimes tapping works, sometimes not. ​Users need to be able to do normal chart interactions like tap a point to see the value and toggle series on/off in the legend.  If I disable FastClick, chart tapping works fine.

FastClick has a built-in way to bypass an element.  You add the "needsclick" CSS class, and it leaves that element alone.  I put this CSS class on the div the chart is rendered in, but each clickable element in the chart apparently also needs to have the "needsclick" class added to it.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up.  I added "needsclick" to all SVG elements after the chart rendered, and the iPad clicking was still really weird.  Sometimes it worked, but not consistently.

I think these libraries are both trying to solve the same problem and stepping on each other to do it, so I removed FastClick.

This was with FastClick 1.0.6 and Kendo UI v2015.1.408.